# How to be sure that channel.basic_publish has succeeded (internet connection error, ...)?

Tags: rabbitmq

Im doing this :

```
channel.basicPublish("myexchange", "routing", MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN,
                "message".getBytes());
```

I would like to retry later to send the message if the publish didn't succeeded (connection loss, ...) but basicPublish is a void function and there is no callback in the arguments

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking an HA client, 
By default you have to implement the feature by your self.

If you use java there is :
https://github.com/joshdevins/rabbitmq-ha-client (it's just a bit old but it think it still work).

Anyway, if you want implement the functionality you have catch the exception and re-try later.

If the client lose the connection you should re-connect the client before re-send the message.

On the version 3.3.0 the last features is implemented by default to the java client:

> ### java client
>
> enhancements
>   14587 support automatically reconnecting to server(s) if connection is
>         interrupted

This point is very important you want send the messages sequentially.

A simple solution is put the messages in a client list and then remove the message from the list only if the message has been sent correctly.

I think you could find interesting also the [Publisher Acknowledgements](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)